# 11 Column 84 Row LED Matrix MicroController?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, led, led-matrix

I am a total novice and have the need to make a 11x84 LED Matrix for a project I am working on, and was wondering if this would be possible. I made an 8x8 prototype but have realized that my ARDUINO UNO will not have enough pins for this task.
Are there any micro controllers with enough pins, or any other ways around this?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use some shift registers (LED drivers) in daisy chain and you will have theoretically unlimited outputs.

Comment: And when you become more advanced, maybe some I2C based multiplexers.

Comment: Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and clarify your question. The answer is 'yes its possible', there are a milliion ways to do this. Please narrow it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common ways to tackle this kind of problem.

### 1. Shift Registers

As has been noted in the comments using shift registers can give you a huge number of outputs using just a handful of microcontroller IO pins. There are specific LED driving shift registers available that are designed for just this kind of thing, such as the STP16CP05. There are more complex ones, such as the TLC5940 or TLC59116, both of which provide PWM, but that can get in the way of multiplexing the LEDs unless you take great care.

Coupling some "normal" shift registers (74HC595) with some suitable P-channel MOSFETs or PNP transistors as high side switches to drive the rows (anodes), along with a bank of STP16CP05 shift registers as the column sinks (cathodes) could be achieved using just three pins on the microcontroller (clock, data and latch).

For lots of LEDs though this rapidly becomes quite hard for the microcontroller to update fast enough. So:

### 2. Think modular

You have already created an 8x8 matrix using 16 pins of a microcontroller. So why not do the same again, multiple times? Have all of them communicating on a bus (SPI, I2C, etc), and send instructions to each module telling it what to display. Each individual module is then responsible for performing the multiplexing and refreshing of the image on its portion of the screen.

There are also dedicated chips designed for this purpose, such as the MAX7219 which can directly drive an 8x8 matrix through an SPI interface.

### 3. Intelligent LEDs

LEDs such as the WS2812 and similar connect in a chain using a simple serial protocol. You can connect many hundreds of these LEDs together, and often come as pre-manufactured strips sold by the metre. These are an excellent option if you want to create a full-colour display.

Comment: Wow you guys answer questions fast.

Comment: Or you go with the smart LED option. If you use something like the WS2812 you can create a theoretically infinity long chain of LEDs and set each one to a different colour while keeping the electronics very simple. It's more expensive, will use more power and has a potentially slower update rate depending on the length of the chain but it does also give you full colour. There are software libraries around to help you drive them. Whether this is an option or completely pointless depends a lot on your final application.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, there is that option too. It kind of comes under the "dedicated chip" but without the multiplexing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, alot of this may have gone over my head as, like previously mentioned, I am completely new electronics. But his may point me in the right direction.  This project is for a Put to Light project im working on, so i need individual control of each LED :)